# Hadoop proxyserver redirect and other confusion

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, proxy, jetty

I've been in the process of starting a small Hadoop cluster for my university. Right now, I'm working on getting the HTTP proxy server to work, defined by `yarn.web-proxy.address` in the `yarn-site.xml` file. When I try to connect to the specified host and port, I'm greeted with a directory listing with just a "webapps" directory, and some empty directories in there. This is obviously not the Hadoop proxy page.

Things get stranger when I try to visit a job page; for example,

http://**node1.my.host.edu:8090**/proxy/application_1418742927193_0001/A

will end up redirecting to the internal address, that is,

http://**node1:8088**/proxy/application_1418742927193_0001/A

I have noticed that when the proxyserver is started, this line is in the logs:

`INFO org.mortbay.log: Extract jar:file:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.5.2.jar!/webapps/proxy to /tmp/Jetty_node1_my_host_edu_8090_proxy____j93dru/webapp`

So for some reason, the proxy is copying a "default" proxy page to the machine and serving it.

Which I cannot access, because it's bound to the internal IP address. What's going on here? Why is Hadoop's proxy server not proxying?